# QGIS 3.0 Page Setup

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

I'm having problems with creating a DIN A 2 Layout in QGIS 3.0

Where can I define the page size? I defined it in the arrangement settings ("Page Setup") but when I create a rectangle the Layout is still in DIN A 4 ...

Answer (score 3):

go with your mouse to the layout page und press the right mouse-button. then you can change the page properties